# laravel get data without applying casts

Tags: laravel, casting

I am doing

```
Model::get()->toArray()
```

to get all the data from my table but the model has a cast on the dates.

```
protected $casts = ['date' => 'datetime:D, M d Y'];
```

I want to be able to get all the data without applying the cast and just the original datetime format. Is there a way to control when the cast is applied.

Comment: You can remove the `date` attribute from the `$casts` array.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to control. I need the cast normally but just for this one section need all the raw values without any casts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get all attributes as they are, by using

```
Model::get()->transform(function ($item) {
    return $item->getOriginal();
}))->toArray();
```

Also can use `getOriginal()` as

```
$model->getOriginal('created_at')
```

on any model to get the original value whenever it's needed.

Note : `getOriginal()` will include all the `$hidden` attributes of the model.

Comment: I have just tried it and it says the getOriginal does not exist. Do i need a certain version of laravel for that call.

Comment: Laravel 7+ you can use getRawOriginal() method.

Answer (score 22):

## Laravel 7+

As Sam mentioned for Laravel 7+ you can use:

```
$model->getRawOriginal('created_at')
```

Answer (score 3):

`getOriginal('date')` and `getRawOriginal('date')` return the unmodified values !

If you want to get the current value without cast, you can use `getAttributes()['date']`

Comment: this answer is the best for laravel 5